# Rails 3.2 has_one build: undefined method serialized_attributes for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I am using Rails 3.2. I am trying to build an object for a has_one relation (each driver has one cdl_driving_license). I have done similar tasks many times before and it worked perfectly fine. This particular case I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `serialized_attributes' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my related code:

driver.rb

```
has_one :cdl_driving_license, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :cdl_driving_license, :allow_destroy => true
```

cdl_driving_license.rb

```
belongs_to  :driver
```

drivers_controller.rb

```
def new
 @driver = Driver.new
 @driver.build_cdl_driving_license
 #more code...
end
```

Any idea what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The record I was trying to build belongs to a table that contained a column with a reserved name (I had a column called "class"). DUH!

Answer (score 0):

In your new method, are you trying to do:
@driver.cdl_driving_license.build(*params for cdl driving license here*)?

Comment: No. As far as I understand, if the association was defined using has_one, we use the "build_association" function. For has_many, it should be "association.build". In my case, I have a has_one association..

Comment: I just changed my association to has_many, and used "@driver.cdl_driving_licenses.build". With these changes, I still get the same error "undefined method serialized attributes for nil:NilClass", from the "build" line..